# How to use UiObject#setText to set non-Latin alphabets (e.g. umlaut) in Android's uiautomator

Tags: android

According to the source code of Android 4.1.1_r1:

**com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject**'s `setText(String text)` method will first `clearTextField()` and then `return getInteractionController().sendText(text);`

And in **com.android.uiautomator.core.InteractionController**, the `sendText` method actually convert `text.toCharArray()`, then return `KeyEvent[]` by calling `nativeGetEvents()`.

Of course the **android.view.KeyEvent** only contains telephone keys, no umlaut(ä,ö,ü,ß) or other charset.  But there does have a KeyEvent called `public static final int KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH = 204;`

While the problem is **InteractionController** class seems like being removed after Android 4.2, thus I could not hack it via sending any KeyEvent directly.

Could anyone tell me if there is any solution or workaround to send non-Latin alphabets to the emulator?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [an IME](https://github.com/sumio/uiautomator-unicode-input-helper) to convert encoded text using only ASCII characters into Unicode text.
You can set non-Latin alphabets in an editable field after installing the IME.

Please see [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618355/2925059) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that's not the ideal solution.  It's the limitation of using KeyEvent, which is used by Android Instrumentation.