# android uiautomator: UIObject.setText with japanese characters fails

Tags: android, testing, functional-testing, android-uiautomator

I am using the android Ui Automator for testing my application. My problem is that the uiObject.setText method does not accept japanese characters.

Is there a way to achieve the goal of setting japanese characters to a android widget over the ui automator framework?

Thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the same problem, so I wrote [an IME](https://github.com/sumio/uiautomator-unicode-input-helper) to convert encoded text using only ASCII characters into Unicode text.

You can set Japanese characters in an editable field by using it:

```
import jp.jun_nama.test.utf7ime.helper.Utf7ImeHelper;

....

// gets UiObject which refers to editable text
UiObject editText = ...; 
// inputs German umlaut characters
editText.setText(Utf7ImeHelper.e("Danke schön"));
// OR
// inputs Japanese characters
editText.setText(Utf7ImeHelper.e("ありがとう"));
....
```

Please see [README.md](https://github.com/sumio/uiautomator-unicode-input-helper/blob/master/README.md) for more detail.